# How do I return object values in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if its actually a object but that's what it says in the console.

I have a object that lookes like this

```
[{"id_no":"6798","name":"Annunication Of The Bvm","address1":"27335 N 8Th St "},
{"id_no":"6815","name":"Francis Of Paola  ","address1":"21229 Conselyea St "}]
```

How do I display the value of "name" if a for loop. This is what I tried with no success

```
  success:function(data){

                console.log(data);
                var pardata = JSON.stringify(data);

                for(name in pardata) {
                    if(pardata.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        var value = pardata[name];
                         alert(value);
                         console.log(value);
                    }
                }

           }
```

Comment: Do not use a for in loop over an array.

Comment: Then what should i use

Comment: Use a simple for loop to iterate over array elements. You can do a `for... in` loop inside that array. You actually have an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/luxevuzefi/edit?html,js,output)

```
var val=[{"id_no":"6798","name":"Annunication Of The Bvm","address1":"27335 N 8Th St "},
{"id_no":"6815","name":"Francis Of Paola  ","address1":"21229 Conselyea St "}]
//Method 1
$('button').click(function(){
  $.each(val,function(i,e){
    $('div').append('<p>'+e.name+'</p>');     
  });  
})
//Method 2
$('button').click(function(){
  $pList='';
  $.each(val,function(i,e){
    $pList+='<p>'+e.name+'</p>';     
  });
  $('div').html($pList);
})
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to using. append() I would like it to clear every time I click the button

Comment: using this stuff  `innerHTML` `+=` `$('div')[0].innerHTML+='<p>'+e.name+'</p>';`

Answer (score 2):

You have an `Array` of `objects` - and an Array is an object, so yeah. You have to iterate the array and then display the property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].name);
}
```

Your issue was with using `for...in` (on a string version of your array) - which is used to iterate the properties of an object. `name` was being assigned an index of the array - so `data[name]` was actually selecting an object at that index. `data[name].name` would've probably worked - but that's not the correct way to iterate an array.